# PLT Web Server with multiple virtual hosts

Tags: racket

Friends, tell me please how to make multiple virtual hosts in PLT Web Server that comes with Racket programming language? I read docs but didn't find detailed information on this topic with examples.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the PLT web server request structure include the hostname that was used to contact the host? It should be possible to dispatch on this.

This is not example code, sorry....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Racket web server does support virtual hosting. Read up more about [`dispatch-host`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server-internal/dispatch-host.html). Sorry, I don't have example code either.